When a band is performing live at a venue, would you say "live at [venue]" or "live at the [venue]"?
Basically what the title says. I've seen both used before.
Ex.: "Live at Civic Arena" vs. "Live at the Civic Arena".

It depends on the venue. Some take the, (the Met), some don’t (Carnegie Hall).

Some are used both with and without "the", so you can take your choice. It's no different from any other reference to a venue. If in doubt, look at their official website (although even there you may not find consistency.)
